# how to expose a report via high volume portal?

Tags: reporting, high-volume-portal

Is this possible to expose a report via the high volume portal?

Are there any visuaforce/apex examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Only certain objects can be **directly** exposed using the HVCP license. Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities and a number of other Objects are not directly supported by that license. What you have to do to work around it to use custom objects and triggers to "mirror" them through a custom object that portal users can access and view. In essence, you duplicate everything as a custom object that portal users can then see.

I suggest you take a look at [Communities](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) and build a portal around that model if you want to pursue it. That's what I've been working on for the last several months. Fortunately, we're close to finishing and heading towards our final testing phase.

Comment: I found this late yesterday  -  http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf - Allowing Portal Users to View the Reports Tab . This seems to imply we can do it.

Comment: I am not sure if this means I can do it, but I cant control it, or what.

Comment: No, you want to look at [Communities](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf). From the Doc you referenced: "Note: Starting with Summer ’13, the Customer Portal isn’t available for new organizations. Existing organizations continue to have access to the Customer Portal. If you don’t have a Customer Portal, but want to easily share information with your customers, try Communities." Without a custom solution, HVCP license users won't have access to reports.